# An Explanation of Message Maps

Tags: c++, mfc

I come from a C# background and am debugging some legacy C++ code. My google skills are failing me, or perhaps my understanding of the results is lacking, but could anyone provide a brief explanation of what Message Maps are used for?
Many Thanks

Comment: It's been some 15 years or so since I last built an application in MFC, but from what I can recall the message maps links windows message codes to specific functions in your code. Many messages though are implemented in MFC base classes.

Comment: Here is the official documentation on [MFC Message Maps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x0cx6b1.aspx).

Comment: The Windows API is based around a message passing system. Messages in the Windows API are essentially untyped. The missing link between Windows API messages and the MFC message maps are the *"Message Crackers"* (implemented in *windowsx.h*), that add type information. The message maps do the same, plus they add facilities to call into class members (vs. static or free functions, as the message crackers do).

Comment: Here is something I found: http://lnr.irb.hr/ebooks/0789715392/ch03/ch03.htm#Heading5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native Win32 API works by message passing. In particular, an application has one or occasionally more message queues. It retrieves messages using `GetMessage()`. Each message has a type.

In old code, the message processing code started with a `switch(msg.message)`. This switch statement didn't lend itself well to MFC 's intended flexibility. It replaced the `switch` statement with message maps, but both serve the same fundamental purpose: to dispatch each message type to the appropriate handler.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is that virtual function can't easily map a message id, may be in combination with a control id, and again in combination with a specific command id, to a function you write.

Classic Win32 code show us a Window Procedure (WinProc) with large switch case blocks. And they again separate into switch case blocks for WM_COMMAND messages.

With the message maps there is no code bloat with large maps for virtual functions. Also the message maps allows the MFC code to see if a message can be handled or not.

Also they allow easy extension when new messages should be included into the messaging system.

The documentation of the MFC has a [brief explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d1asasd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> In traditional programs for Windows, Windows messages are handled in a large switch statement in a window procedure. MFC instead uses message maps to map direct messages to distinct class member functions. Message maps are more efficient than virtual functions for this purpose, and they allow messages to be handled by the most appropriate C++ object — application, document, view, and so on. You can map a single message or a range of messages, command IDs, or control IDs.